# Is there a way to show Persian date in x-axis of Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, persian-calendar

I want to plot a `dataframe` in which the `index` consists of `datetime` values based on [Iranian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars).

I want to set the `x-axis` labels as following:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

axes.scatter(df_day.index.values, df_day.loc[:, item], marker='.')
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d-%b %H:%M'))
```

Consider that I want to print the **months**'s name in Persian instead of default value of `Georgian` calendar such as  `Jun` or `Aug`.

I used [jdatetime](https://pypi.org/project/jdatetime/) to convert the `datetime` in persian calendar but the `plot` function doesn't take it's value as `x-axis` index. then I used [jalaali](https://github.com/jalaali/jalaali-python) to create a `datetime` based on persian calendar that plot accepts it.

now the problem is how to print `x-axis` label as Persian month names? because I want this format:

```
dates.DateFormatter('%d-%b %H:%M')
```

Is there any way of doing that?

**UPDATE**

I used [locale](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) to  access to the POSIX locale database and functionality as following:

```
import locale 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fa_IR')
```

but it only changed the name of `Georgian` months from `English` alphabet in `Persian` alphabet instead of showing `jalali` names such as `فروردین` or `اردیبهشت`.

any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `plotly` instead of `matplotlib` here is a simple example :

```
import datetime
import plotly.express as px

base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(200)]
nums = list(range(200))

fig = px.line(x=date_list, y=nums)
fig.update_xaxes(calendar='jalali')
fig.show()
```

output is like this figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you have a georgian dates column in your dataframe, you can simply use georgian dates in *datetime.date* format for your x-axis, and use this line of code to show them as persian dates.

```
fig.update_xaxes(calendar='jalali')
```

it doesn't need to use jdatetime.

your output would be like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA2XM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use django-jalali-date
Here is the PyPI link to it.
https://pypi.org/project/django-jalali-date/

Comment: Although the attached page contains a possible solution to the question, it is better to add detailed information such as citations or code snippets that point to a given answer, it is also recommended to read [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).